# How to search Column data in tab names and copy related data row into related data sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for search Column data in tab names and copy related data row into related data sheet.

Let me describe it. Please find the attached image.
[image: Sample Image]

In sheet1 there are hundreds of different tag numbers(Column C).
Please find the attached sample sheet [Sample link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mlXQ_QsWdzqJ6IwWi_RASsxBiECfOb7N4bc0bjpylDY/edit#gid=0)

And I wrote a script to create a new tab for each Tag no in column C.

So what I need to do is, I need to match column C data with tab name and, copy related row into the related tab.

For an example, row 12 is D11. So I need to copy this row 12 data into tab called 'D11'. Like wise for all the data in column C.

While I was searching for this, I was able to find a code for creating a new tab for all the data in Column C. But couldnt go further.

```
​function CreateNewSheet() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var BlankSheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('BlankSheet')); //access to the sheet by name
var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
var getNames = sheet1.getRange("C:C").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
    var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
    if (copy) {
        Logger.log("Sheet already exists");
     } else {
        BlankSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(getNames[i]);
        ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]));
        ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());
    }
}
}
```

​​I was testing different codes for 4 days now. But still couldnt make it to work.
I'm not expert in this. Looking for your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, it adds the sheet and updates the values, update as per your need.

```
Sub t1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim lr As Long

lr = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets("Sheet1")
    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But as I'm going to use this with Google Sheets. So I have no idea about how to implement this VB code to work with Google Sheets.